# How to run Jest tests on Jenkins Server

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jestjs

I'm attempting to run my [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) Test during Jenkins deployment. If I ssh into the server, I can sudo into the Jenkins user and successfully run the tests from the workspace. However, I get an error when I attempt to build the project from the GUI. Here is my project setup:

I have installed the nodejs plugin, which in turn installs gulp, jest-cli and babel globally. 
[image]

Then in build steps:

[image]

The test fails with this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getResourceByPath' of null
    at Loader.getDependenciesFromPath (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PHPStaging/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:570:39)
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PHPStaging/node_modules/jest-cli/src/TestRunner.js:250:22
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
Running 6 test suites...
 FAIL  resources/__tests__/myTest.js
```

It appears that Node is having trouble requiring modules from the tests, but I'm not totally sure. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Um, yes, but it wasn't straightforward. Did you get it working?

Comment: No I didn't. Any suggestions on how you got it to work? Even some links to resources you used would be helpful.

Comment: So, a good place to start, is when you run a build, Jenkins will print to the console which node version it's using and the location. Something like this `/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_8.1.0/bin/npm install -g jest-cli`. ssh into your jenkins server, and run your test suite as your jenkins user running that node install. Our problem ended up being a ton of file permission issues for the jenkins user.

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated.