# How to deploy node app to remote host from Jenkins?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, deployment, gitlab

This is  Jenkins file in the root of node app directory:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        pollSCM('* * * * *')
    }
    stages {
        stage("deploy") {
            steps {
            sh "scp"
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I configured Jenkins to connect to remote gitlab node proj repo to checkout  node project along with Jenkinsfile and run the project's Jenkinsfile. This part works fine but what to do now to perform (note that Jenkins server and the server on which node js is running as well as gitlab repo are all remote to each other):

```
run these commands on remote server on which node app is running

cd ~/mynodeproj 

pm2 stop mynodeproj 

copy project source files from Jenkins server to remote server where 
node app is running 

npm install 

export NODE_ENV=production 

pm2 start mynodeproj
```

How to achieve this?

Do I need to setup private/public keypair on server running jenkins so that jenkins server can do scp to copy file to remote server running node app?

Comment: Correct. Once you've done that, you can then use scp to copy the files and ssh to run these commands at the remote server.

Comment: @ace: Did you try all three answers? Can you choose what's the best way for `bounty`

Answer (score 7):

I'm suggest we can use [Rocketeer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pJsF.png) for this case.

Here is `Rocketeer` tree on my Jenkins Server for NodeJS App

```
$ tree .rocketeer/
.rocketeer/
├── config.php
├── hooks.php
├── logs
│   ├── develop--20170613.log
│   ├── develop--20170614.log
│   ├── develop--20170616.log
│   ├── staging--20180323.log
│   ├── staging--20180324.log
│   ├── staging--20180326.log
│   ├── production--20180223.log
│   ├── production--20180226.log
│   ├── production--20180227.log
│   ├── production--20180227.log
│   └── custom-environment--20180328.log
├── paths.php
├── remote.php
├── scm.php
├── stages.php
└── strategies.php
```

- You can manage remote environment of NodeJS App: Develop, Staging, Production (at `config.php` file)
- It's will pull newest source code on your Gitlab and keep releases version like `Capistrano` (at `remote.php` file)
- It's can run your `pm2 command line` after deployed newest source code (at `hooks.php` file)
- It's already help run `npm install` NodeJS packages.

---

So here is my Jenkins Job setting:

**Source Code Management**

[image]

**Build Triggers**

[image]

**Build**

[image]

```
#!/bin/bash -el
cd $JENKINS_HOME/app-deploy/app-socketio
rocketeer deploy --on="develop"
```

**develop** mean connect to Develop Remote Server (at `.rocketeer\config.php` file)

```
'connections'      => [
    'develop' => [
        'host'      => '35.xx.xx.xx',
        'username'  => 'ec2-user',
        'password'  => '',
        'key'       => '/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/foo.pem',
        'keyphrase' => '',
        'agent'     => '',
        'db_role'   => true,
    ],
    'staging' => [
        'host'      => '34.xx.xx.xx',
        'username'  => 'ec2-user',
        'password'  => '',
        'key'       => '/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/bar.pem',
        'keyphrase' => '',
        'agent'     => '',
        'db_role'   => true,

    ],
    'production' => [
        'host'      => '18.xx.xx.xx:63612',
        'username'  => 'ec2-user',
        'password'  => '',
        'key'       => '/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/woot.pem',
        'keyphrase' => '',
        'agent'     => '',
        'db_role'   => true,
    ],
    'custom-environment' => [
        'host'      => '13.xx.xx.xx:63612',
        'username'  => 'ec2-user',
        'password'  => '',
        'key'       => '/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/test.pem',
        'keyphrase' => '',
        'agent'     => '',
        'db_role'   => true,
    ],
],
```

And run `pm2` command line configure at `hooks.php` file

```
'after'  => [
    'setup'   => [],
    'deploy'  => [
            "pm2 delete mynodeproj", //Delete old pm2 task
            "pm2 start src/mynodeproj.js", //Start new mynodeproj
    ],
    'cleanup' => [],
],
```

Hope this can help you!!

Answer (score 4):

> What to do now to perform (note that Jenkins server and the server on which node js is running as well as gitlab repo are all remote to each other):

Those command should be in a file part of your Git repo, meaning checked out in the workspace used by the pipeline.

From there, you can scp that script to the server:

```
sh 'scp -r script user@server:/path/server'
```

And execute it through ssh, provided the private/public key of the remote user is deployed on the agent (or passed through the [ssh-agent plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/)):

```
sh 'ssh user@server /path/server/script'
```

The trick though, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610346/how-to-run-jest-tests-on-jenkins-server?rq=1#comment85572904_35610346), is that the PATH of an ssh session is fairly limited, and might not include node, if node is *not* installed in a standard path like `/usr/bin`.
So you might want to modify your script in order to use *absolute* paths for your executable (like `/absolute/path/to/node`)

Comment: so file named 'script' is bash shell script stating with #!/bin/sh ? It looks like a good solution but the issue seems to be that as now all the commands execute in a separate script file instead of executing as steps within Jenkinsfile. In this later case if any step fails for example the step "pm2 stop mynodeproj " fails Jenkins pipeline build will stop and it will go red. But in your solution Jenkins will not know if any commands in script failed?

Comment: @ace You can start your script with `#!/bin/sh -x`: you will see exactly which line fails if there is a failure in the script execution, that is)

Comment: Also its not clear how to do scp source code to remote server running node? I mean if I push a file from local PC to gitlap repo, this will trigger Jenkins to check out the changed file. After this how Jenkins is going to scp only this changed file to remote server running node app? Also your script solution may have to be broken in two scripts one initially stop the running node app and then Jenkins scp changed source file(s) to remote server, after this second script runs the rest of the commands. Do I need to setup git repo on remote server running node app and config Jenkins to push to it?

Comment: @ace I mentioned in the answer how to scp a file. scp is for a remote server where there is no Jenkins or Git.

Answer (score 4):

`Your question is how to deploy your application to remote host from jenkins`

easiest solution

**1.using Jenkins File**

If your using a pipeline project, then you will notice a Pipeline Syntax option, just select ssh Publisher:send artifacts over SSH (you'llneed the plugin Publish over SSH plugin)

[image]
Add an SSH server

- Source Files :mention the files you wish to transfer (**/*.war takes
  the WAR file only)
- Remove prefix : target(WAR files will generally be
  located in a target folder so i'm telling I don't want the target
  folder to be copied only my WAR)
- Remote Directory : Leave it blank(
  since your taking it from your project)
- Exec command : Commands to be executed after copying the files( like starting tomcat or unzip any properties files and place at a particular location - in your case the commands to start node from your server)

Finally just click Generate Pipeline Script and BOOM, you get the script (it internally does an scp) just copy and paste it into your Pipeline file and your done :)

[image])

**2.Publish over SSH**

You can do the same thing( follow the above steps adding details only) in a normal Jenkins project in the Post Build Action
If you don't have a Pipeline Project (helps if you don't have/know a Pipeline Project)

[image]

`Do I need to setup private/public keypair on server running jenkins so that jenkins server can do scp to copy file to remote server running node app?`

Yes its required(Recommended) you can add the deatils as shown below in Jenkins under Manage Jenkins, Configure Jenkins Under Publish over SSH and you can test your connection .

[image]

Hope this was useful :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider doing this with ansible and just call your ansible playbook from: Build -> Execute Shell

https://dzone.com/articles/running-ansible-playbooks-from-jenkins

You can have ansible manage all your remote environments.