# Jenkins: -bash: command not found

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to build my Node.js application using Jenkins, but I'm getting this error:

```
    -bash: npm: command not found
    -bash: pm2: command not found
    Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

I created a deploy file and added it to my Execute shell in Jenkins, and it looks like this:

```
-#!/bin/sh
ssh ubuntu@development-server:ip <<EOF
    cd ~/nodeweb
    git pull
    npm install
    pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js
    exit
EOF
```

On my development server, I have installed the npm and pm2 modules.

Comment: Why do you have a `-` before your `#!`?

Comment: You should read this tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801472/how-to-deploy-node-app-to-remote-host-from-jenkins/49849848#49849848

Comment: This is a path issue. If you define the path, this problem will resolve.

Answer (score 1):

This is because a normal ssh session opens the shell in **non-interactive mode** and does not source the `.bashrc` file.

The `PATH` for your npm and pm2 modules could be configured in the `.bashrc` file and thereby throws the not found error when you try to do `npm install` via the non-interactive shell.

For ssh to use the interactive mode simply use `-i` flag in your ssh command.

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh ubuntu@development-server:ip 'bash -i' <<EOF
    cd ~/nodeweb
    git pull
    npm install
    pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js
    exit
EOF
```